# How to bind collection of images in Xamarin Forms Cross-Platform

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, xamarin.forms

In `WPF`, I can easily bind a collection of image sources to a `WrapPanel` with image template for instance:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourChildItems}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I cannot find an alternative `Cross-platform Xamarin Forms` way of binding my `Image` collection to any panel based control.

Comment: https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/ImageGallery

Answer (score 1):

There is an equivalent of `ItemsControl` in Xamarin.Forms labs called `RepeaterView`. It has support for item `DataTemplate` as well as ItemsPanelTemplate. Check the [wiki page](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/RepeaterView) on GitHub and this [forum thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21635/xforms-needs-an-itemscontrol) for examples

Comment: Thank you for telling about the `RepeaterView`. I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to here and download `WrapLayout.cs`.
2. Add it your project in Visual Studio.
3. Then you should define its namespace in xaml

   `xmlns:xf="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms"`
4. You should use it like this code:

```
<ScrollView>
     <xf:WrapLayout x:Name="wrp" />   
</ScrollView>
```

5. Finally you can add items in code behind.