# A layout which can wrap contents of a collection which is inside a Listview

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, itemscontrol

I am trying to implement a list of employees working in departments. There are several departments and several employees in a department. Following is my code and I have difficulty in scrolling and wrapping contents (Employee image and Name). As for wrapping the contents, if a row does not have enough space, I want the contents (image and employee's first name) to be displayed in a new line.

So far, I have tried several options but to no avail. I'm using [`ItemsControl`](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/blob/master/src/XamU.Infrastructure/Controls/ItemsControl.cs) I also tried adding a `StackLayout` instead of the [`WrapLayout`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UserInterface/CustomLayout/WrapLayout/ImageWrapLayout/Layout/WrapLayout.cs).

Can anyone please tell me how to fix the scrolling issue and content wrapping issue? Are there any workarounds or any other layouts I can use? Thank you.

**XAML**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Margin="20,20,20,20">
                        <Label Text="{Binding DepartmentName}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding DepartmentId}" />

                        <local:ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
                            <local:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                            <local:WrapLayout>
                                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                                                       WidthRequest="60"
                                                       HeightRequest="60"/>
                                                <Label
                                                       Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                                    LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
                                            </local:WrapLayout>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </local:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </local:ItemsControl>

                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

**Update 1:**

**Classes**

*Department.cs*

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    // and several other properties

    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

*Employee.cs*

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl{ get; set; }

    // and several other properties
}
```

**Update 2**

Seems like the scrolling does not happen in only one of my testing devices. But still need a layout which is capable of wrapping controls.

**Update 3**
I want the data to be displayed as in the image below. But right now, with the above code, the contents in the `WrapLayout` are not wrapped but they are resized in order to fit into one line. I want them to be wrapped if there's no space in the first line.

[image]

Comment: Is ItemsControl a kind of ListView component? You can not use nested listviews nor listview inside a scrollview and vice versa. Seems like you need a grouped listview. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/45613700/8093394) about the same problem

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza `ItemsControl` is actually [this](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/blob/master/src/XamU.Infrastructure/Controls/ItemsControl.cs). I used a nested `ListView` (without `ScrollView`) previously but it did not display the data properly and of course it is not efficient, from what I saw in most of the posts. I tried the above link you have mentioned. But my class is a bit different. I have updated my question. If you can, please have a look at it. Thank you.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Thank you for that link. I tried it. It does not, however, serve my main purpose. :( Which is to wrap contents. The grid is not dynamic (since this is a collection) in this case. I want to able to go without mentioning the row and column indexes. :( Will you be able to help me this :(

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look

Comment: Sorry for my bad english, but what do you mean when you say "wrap contents"? The grid at that case was the chosen layout to that context. With the answer I gave, I refers to the proposed concept of grouped list view as you can see [here](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/) and [here](http://danielhindrikes.se/xamarin/grouping-a-listview-xamarin-forms/), for example, if I understood correctly your need. You should adjust the group header template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you mention `WrapLayout`, I am assuming you mean [this one](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/CustomLayout/WrapLayout/ImageWrapLayout/Layout) as defined [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/CustomLayout/WrapLayout/).

Also, as you are already using [`ItemsControl`](https://github.com/xamarinhq/xamu-infrastructure/blob/master/src/XamU.Infrastructure/Controls/ItemsControl.cs), I would recommend tweaking it to support `WrapLayout` instead of `StackLayout`. For example:

```
public class ItemsControl : WrapLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        "ItemsSource", typeof(IList), typeof(ItemsControl), propertyChanging: OnItemsSourceChanged);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the items source - can be any collection of elements.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The items source.</value>
    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        "ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ItemsControl));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the item template used to generate the visuals for a single item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The item template.</value>
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public ItemsControl()
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(0);
        Margin = new Thickness(0);
    }

    static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        ((ItemsControl)bindable).OnItemsSourceChangedImpl((IList)oldValue, (IList)newValue);
    }

    void OnItemsSourceChangedImpl(IList oldValue, IList newValue)
    {
        // Unsubscribe from the old collection
        if (oldValue != null)
        {
            INotifyCollectionChanged ncc = oldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (ncc != null)
                ncc.CollectionChanged -= OnCollectionChanged;
        }

        if (newValue == null)
        {
            Children.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            FillContainer(newValue);
            INotifyCollectionChanged ncc = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
            if (ncc != null)
                ncc.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method takes our items source and generates visuals for
    /// each item in the collection; it can reuse visuals which were created
    /// previously and simply changes the binding context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newValue">New items to display</param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException"></exception>
    void FillContainer(IList newValue)
    {
        var template = ItemTemplate;
        var visuals = Children;

        if (template == null)
            throw new NotSupportedException("ItemTemplate must be specified!");

        var newVisuals = new List<View>(Children); //using a list to avoid multiple layout refresh
        Children.Clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < newVisuals.Count; i++)
        {
            newVisuals[i].IsVisible = i < newValue.Count;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < newValue.Count; i++)
        {
            var dataItem = newValue[i];

            if (visuals.Count > i)
            {
                if (template != null)
                {
                    var visualItem = visuals[i];
                    visualItem.BindingContext = dataItem;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (template != null)
                {
                    // Pull real template from selector if necessary.
                    var dSelector = template as DataTemplateSelector;
                    if (dSelector != null)
                        template = dSelector.SelectTemplate(dataItem, this);

                    var view = template.CreateContent() as View;
                    if (view != null)
                    {
                        view.BindingContext = dataItem;
                        newVisuals.Add(view);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var child in newVisuals) //wish they had a nice AddRange method here
            if(child.IsVisible)
                Children.Add(child);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the data source collection implements
    /// collection change notifications and the data has changed.
    /// This is not optimized - it simply replaces all the data.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Sender.</param>
    /// <param name="e">E.</param>
    void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FillContainer((IList)sender);
    }
}
```

And then change your XAML to:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}" HasUnevenRows="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Margin="20,20,20,20">
                    <Label Text="{Binding DepartmentName}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding DepartmentId}" />

                    <local:ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}">
                        <local:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                                                   WidthRequest="60"
                                                   HeightRequest="60"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding FirstName}"
                                           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </local:ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </local:ItemsControl>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot again. Earlier I changed the `StackLayout` in the `ItemsControl` (in the code) to `WrapLayout` and it also worked. Tried this again now, it's also working.

Comment: Also, since you mentioned in my previous question that there are inefficiencies in using `ItemsControl`, will this `RepeaterView` mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32990855/7196681), be an efficient replacement?

Comment: As per understanding they are practically the same - although `ItemsControl` does have some recycling behavior in lieu of virtualization; I don't see that in `RepeaterView`

Comment: OK. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: When I try to update the Collection, the list or its children does not show any changes. I have set the `Collection` in the `ViewModel` to null and set a new value. But it doesn't help either. Can you please tell me what is happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm using [`FreshMvvm`](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm). So it automatically notifies right?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on `OnItemsSourceChangedImpl` to ensure that its called when ItemsSource changes - technically it should if IPC is applied.

Comment: Also you have the attribute `ImplementPropertyChanged` set on the view-model - right?

Comment: I put a breakpoint there. It is only hit when the List is loading for the first time. Not when I try to update, Yes, I'm setting the value in the `ViewModel`

Comment: Have you set fody attribute `ImplementPropertyChanged` on view model? Because then the method will be called when you set the value. If the method is not getting called then there is something wrong with property change notification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155987/discussion-between-curiousity-and-g-sharada).

Comment: Hi thanks for this I have implemented it and it works nicely. However, I still have a problem regarding the data context inside the DataTemplate can you see my question here and offer any ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46771114/xamarin-data-context-in-itemscontrol